# How to add dot before the first letter in a string?

Tags: java, regex, string, groovy

Consider this string `s = " GOTO ok1"`.
How to add a efficient `if` check whether there exists only a single dot before a letter and after a space.
If dot doesn't exists, I want to add a dot before the first letter.
I want the string to be this `s =  " .GOTO ok1"`. Notice it  still holds the leading space.

How to efficiently do this in java(using regex)/ groovy (using closures)?
Does a one or two liner code exists for this ?

Comment: What about `s=" 123BLAH"` or `s=" $XYZ"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java you could try something like this:

```java
Pattern.compile("^(\\s*)(?:\\.)*(\\w)").matcher(input).replaceFirst("$1.$2");
```

It would produce following outputs:

```
" GOTO ok1"    -> " .GOTO ok1",
" .GOTO ok1"   -> " .GOTO ok1",
"GOTO ok1"     -> ".GOTO ok1",
"  ..GOTO ok1" -> "  .GOTO ok1",
"       "      -> "       "
```

[Matcher.replaceFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String)) replaces first occurrence of the pattern with the provided replacement. `$1` and `$2` in the replacement string are references to capture-groups within the pattern:

given string `"  ....GOTO ok1"`:

- full pattern match: `"  ....G"`
- group 1: `"  "` (leading spaces)
- group 2: `"G"` (first letter)
- thus, `"  ....G"` is replaced with `"  .G"`

In practice you would rather want to compile the pattern once and reuse it:

```
class RegexTest {

    private final static Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^(\\s*)(?:\\.)*(\\w)");

    @Test
    void test() {
        var examples = Map.of(
            " GOTO ok1",  " .GOTO ok1",
            " .GOTO ok1", " .GOTO ok1",
            "GOTO ok1", ".GOTO ok1",
            "      ..GOTO ok1", "      .GOTO ok1",
            "       ", "       "
        );
        examples.forEach((input, expected) -> {
            assertEquals(expected, PATTERN.matcher(input).replaceFirst("$1.$2"));
        });
    }

}
```

Performance-wise, regular expressions are pretty expensive, the most effective would be a simple loop:

```java
String format(String in) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i<in.length(); i++) {
        switch (in.charAt(i)) {
            case ' ':
                builder.append(' ');
                break;
            case '.':
                break;
            default:
                builder.append(".").append(in.substring(i));
                return builder.toString();
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew how to do this with loop. But I wanted to see how you can do this with regex. Can you explain what does replaceFirst() does ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to process a large text looking for these occurrences i don't think its possible in 2 lines of code.Hope this helps or gives you some ideas:

```
    String  d = " GOTO ok1";
    String  b = " .";
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(d); 
    builder.deleteCharAt(0);
    System.out.println(b+builder); // Does the job in your example but prob not what you are looking for
    
    String s = " .GOTO ok1";
    String count = s.trim();
    System.out.println(count); // This will only get rid of spaces
    
    int n = 2;
    String upToNCharacters = s.substring(0, Math.min(s.length(), n));
    int x = upToNCharacters.indexOf('.');
    // Here you can add IF x is 0 or 1 then "." exists
    // But it is not 2 lines of code as you requested
    
    System.out.println(x);
```